# Number of stops during trip - Dynamic programming algorithm

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, dynamic-programming, greedy-algorithms

I am attending a course about algorithm design, and I have found an old test which has once been submitted. However, I don't have the solutions to it, and I am having some trouble with one specific excersise. This is the text:

Matt is planning a road trip from City A to City B, and he wants to minimize the number of breaks during the journey. He has a limit of n kilometers he can drive before needing a break. His map includes the distances between rest stops along the route.

The problem is simalar to the one appearing in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/508430) question, but the answers do not really go in depth about the actual algorithm

I am trying to build the algorithm with dynamic programming. The main idea is that for each possible stop, I check what is more convenient between stopping and not stopping. This is what I have come up with:

$$
OPT(km, i) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
1+OPT(km, i+1) & d_i > km \\ 
min(1+OPT(km, i+1), OPT(n-d_i, i+1)) & d_i\leq km\\ 
0 & i=n
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

Where $i$ is the number of the station, $n$ is the total number of stations, $km$ is the maximum drivable distance without stopping and $d_i$ is the distance between the $i$'th station and the previous one.

I have thought about making it more efficient by using memoization, but I don't see how this could be done since the number of km left might vary between every call to $OPT$.
I have no clue about how to prove that this algorithm actually gives the best possible solution, nor do I know what its time complexity is. I guess each call to $OPT$ is constant time, but the number of subproblems seems big.

Any help will be gratly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, you don't need any dynamic programming to solve this problem, and a greedy solution works great. The greedy solution is: go as far as possible without taking a break from City $A$ (i.e. go to the furthest rest stop which is less than $n$ kilometers away). Repeat this process until you reach City $B$. This runs in time $O(n)$ by using, say, two pointers.

Why can we do this? Well, let $f(i)$ be the minimum number of breaks you need to reach rest stop $i$ (let's define City $A$ to be rest stop $0$ and City $B$ to be rest stop $m$). Then, $f(0) \le f(1)\le f(2) \le \ldots \le f(m)$.

Now, let's suppose we have computed $f(0), f(1), \ldots, f(i - 1)$. How can we compute $f(i)$? We may write $f(i) = 1 + \min_{j < i, d(i, j) \le n} f(j)$, where $d(i, j) = d(i, 0) - d(j, 0)$ is the distance between rest stops $i$ and $j$. By the increasing assumption on $f(j)$, it follows that $f(i)$ only depends on the single furthest before it coordinate $j$, which is identical to the greedy approach in the first paragraph.

Your dynamic programming approach looks fairly similar to this in many respects (just with a bit more casework, maybe).

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, this way it seems way simpler. I find it very tricky to understand when to use dynamic programming instead of greedy, but I guess I should try greedy before always.
Thanks again!

Comment: @FarsoFracico you can read CLRS' greedy chapter to see how you can always try to turn a dynamic programming solution into a greedy solution, by proving that only one subproblem would remain by then and other things, since there's always a dynamic programming underpinning of a greedy solution namely optimal substructure